Emulating and Reading Xbox One Controller in Python
I am looking to emulate and read (button presses) on the Xbox One Controller. Unlike the Xbox 360 Controller, it seems that there are not many packages that can do this, and the closest I have come to doing this was using a app called reWASD, it could read my button presses and create new ones. Great, however I would like to make my own program, not be limited to what this app can do. Basically, what I want to do is be able to press a button on my real Xbox One Controller, then from that, press and hold a different button, and process what happens on the screen, for example pressing the Xbox button, then holding X for a specific amount of time. I would appreciate any help that could be provided to me, any place that I could start, etc.

This question is similar to: How can I get input from an Xbox One controller in Python?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@importrandom I also need to emulate the button presses. From what I gathered from that post, it seems that the op just needs to read the input.
